# How do I add image with text inside PdfCell?

Tags: java, image, pdf, itext

I'm trying to add an image followed by text inside PdfCell. So far the best I could achieve was to have the image ABOVE the text. I am, however, want the image to be on the left of the text in the same line. Here's my current code:

```
PdfCell cell = new PdfCell()
cell.addElement(myImage);
Chunk staffChunk = new Chunk("This is my text");
staffChunk.setFont(font);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(staffChunk);
cell.addElement(p);
```

I already did `myImage.setAlignment(Image.LEFT)`. The text is still showing up below the image.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `Image` inside a `Chunk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the image and the text as chunks to a paragrah and then add this paragraph to the cell:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph() { new Chunk(itextImg, 0, 0), "Hello World" };
```

Comment: Finally got it working like this: Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Chunk(groupImage,0,0)); p.add(textChunk);